# Android back button freezes when using onkeydown method or overriding onbackbuttonpressed

Tags: java, android, button, overriding, onkeydown

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

    if (isSub2&&keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctxx, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);

        isReturning = true;

        return false;
    }
    else {
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    }
}
```

There are two Activities Main--Sub2.
When you push a button in Main you can go to Sub2.
This code is in Sub2. I want to use back button on the bottom to make the MainActivity put on the top of stack not killing Sub2.

When I run it on the phone it works all right at first, 
but after few more times of going back in Sub2 and going to Sub2 again 
the back button stops working.

I don't know what is making the back button freeze.. any ideas?

ps) i've tried using handlers inside the method and overriding onBackButtonPressed() instead of using onKeyDown..
but no difference at all..

Comment: can you post a log cat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why your button freezes. It would be helpful to see what you are doing in the main activity. Here's an example that works for me and does not freeze:

You can put this in the main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubActivity.class);
            //****** Uncomment the following line if you want to re-use the subactivity instead of launching a new one
            //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

And this in the sub-activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```